# Applet error/exception logging

Tags: java, logging, applet

I need to log every client side exception/error of applet which we can view on java console. Is there any way so that I can get this error/exception message so that I can resend this to server using ajax. I have to send below message in server side. Please help.

[image: Console error message]

Answer (score 1):

From the stack trace it appears that this was caught by the [Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html).  You should be able to implement your own custom UncaughtExceptionHandler to capture the exception.  Then use the [Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler-java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler-) to install it.  It does require the 'RuntimePermission ("setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler")' in order to install your custom UncaughtExceptionHandler.